# Having trouble dealing with validation of information from edit form

Tags: php, laravel

When a user enters the settings view, the view displays their current information in input fields which can be edited and then saved. However, I am facing a little hurdle which I'm not sure how to avoid. For example:

A user might only want to edit 1 field like the username for example, however, to do that he'd have to change his email or else he'll get a message that the email has already been taken and that is true, the email is already taken by the same user. Also even though the password field is not required, he's gonna get a message that the the password must be at least 5 characters and if I remove that validation, the user will be able to add empty password.

I just want to make it so I can edit only 1 field without having to change the rest.

Here is my view which allows people to change their current account information:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('updateProfile', $user) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="text" name="first_name"  value="{{ $user->first_name }}" />

    <input type="text" name="last_name"  value="{{ $user->last_name }}" />

    <input type="text" name="username"  value="{{ $user->username }}" />

    <input type="email" name="email"  value="{{ $user->email }}" />

    <input type="password" name="password" />

    <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" />

    <input type="file" name="file" />

    {{ csrf_field() }}

    {{ method_field('patch') }}

    <button class='Submit' type="submit" name="submit">Save Changes</button>

</form>
```

And here's my profileUpdate function:

```
public function updateProfile(Request $request, User $user){

    $this->validate($request, [
        'first_name' => 'max:120',
        'last_name' => 'max:120',
        'username' => 'max:120',
        'email' => 'email|unique:users',
        'password' => 'min:5|max:12|confirmed',
        'file' => 'max:1999'
    ]);

    $file = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
    $fileName = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $extension = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
    $fileNameToStore = str_replace(' ', '', $fileNameToStore);
    $path = $request->file('file')->storeAs('public/uploads/profile_pictures/', $fileNameToStore);

    $user->first_name = request('first_name');
    $user->last_name = request('last_name');
    $user->username = request('username');
    $user->email = request('email');
    $user->password = bcrypt(request('password'));
    $user->profile_picture = $fileNameToStore;

    $user->save();

    return back();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the validations [rule documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#rule-unique) about the `unique` rule, you'll see that you can specify additional parameters:

`unique:table,column,except,idColumn`

With the third parameter you can tell the validator to ignore a certain record in the table.

Change your validation rules to the following:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'first_name' => 'max:120',
    'last_name' => 'max:120',
    'username' => 'max:120',
    'email' => 'email|unique:users,email,'.$user->id,
    'password' => 'min:5|max:12|confirmed',
    'file' => 'max:1999'
]);
```

This should fix your problem.

If for whatever reason you don't have an `id` column as primary key, add that as the last parameter.

Comment: Can I do something similar about the password? Currently, the password input fields are empty by default because they're type password. If I don't want to change the password and leave them empty, I get "The password must be at least 5 characters." but I don't want to remove that validation for when a user actually wants to change his password. Also if I remove it, the user could change his password to nothing. So I only want the password to be changed, If I've written something new in the input field.

Comment: Technically that's a new question, but you could create the rule array without password and check for an input with `if ($request->input('password', false) !== false)` which filters out an empty input. If it's not empty, add an extra rule to the array.